# On the desktop images are being displayed but in Phone Browsers images are not showing up

Tags: html, css

The weblink is escreva.in , on the phone browser it dose not load images, but the desktop version has no issue in loading the images. Any suggestion??

Comment: Welcome, Daksh! Try and make a little mini example of the targeted stuff - with a jsfiddle or codepen etc - and we'll be quicker to help. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daksh.

The Image is a 'background-image' - and the a (link) that has the background image - has no 'shape' - and so, there's nothing to be the background image of (when it's a smaller screen).

When it hits a break-point then the parent is given display:flex - and that just happens to force the link to have a shape that allows for the background image. It's a fluke.

There are many ways to do this differently - but I'm not sure what to suggest for you.

[image]

I suggest you write it differently and ditch that framework:

```css
/* global */
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

picture {
  display: block;/* inline by default */
}


/* module */
.example-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .example-parent {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .text {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="example-parent">
  
  <picture>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1200">
  </picture>
  
  <div class="text">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa vero iste quisquam illo autem harum labore, quia maxime quo suscipit natus delectus deleniti impedit ad ipsum ipsam perspiciatis magni corrupti.</p>
  </div>
  
</section>
```

Example that you can stretch and see in action: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/6w3s8vg0/

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I just wated to ask that why were the images being shown before. Will try implementing your framework.

Comment: When the break-point happens (in your code) - on a larger screen... the parent element turns to 'display: flex.' The default nature of flex - (and your settings in particular) tell the link (with the background-image) to be 100% height of the parent. So, that's why it 'seems to work' - or that "the image is show." I hope that helps! It's really a mess to try and teach something from the middle of so much 'stuff' and with blurry mental models for how things work.

Comment: I can understand explaining this is hard in this nasty code. Thankyou verymuch for your help

Comment: There are many many concepts - underneath this / so, it's not the code really - but just a lot of 'stuff' to try and explain from this starting point.